# The number of bits in a binary representation of a integer

Tags: binary

Q: What is the length (number of bits) of the binary representation of the positive integer n?

I understand that a positive integer can be represented in binary by using the sum of base 2 but I wasn't sure how to find the length of the binary representation for any positive integer n

Answer (score 0):

You can find the length by doing the following:

length = ceil(log(N + 1)/log(2));

that is the length is the ceiling of the log base 2 of N. Since I can't remember the log base 2 function name, I am doing the equivalent above.
You need to N + 1 to correctly account for N being a direct power of 2 and thus needing the one extra bit to represent it. Example N = 8 = 1000 in binary. log base 2 of 8 is 3 and the ceiling of 3 is 3, but log base 2 of 9 is 3.16993 and the ceiling of 3.16993 is 4.